# FlyWay versions

Tags: java, flyway

I have question about versioned migrations

I want create files with such template

**V201709181750__Create_users.sql** - Is this a long number you can use?

And another question
FlyWay launched such scripts

- *V20170918**1500**__Create_users_1.sql*
- *V20170918**1800**__Create_users_2.sql*

Then I commit file *V20170918**1600**__Create_users_3.sql*

When the file hits the middle, and does not become the latest version. How will FlyWay behave in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version number of each migration is stored in the database in **SCHEMA_VERSION** table. Field VERSION is declared with length 50. (nvarchar(50) in SqlServer). 
I assume that 50 symbols is the limit for version string.

Btw, I tried 1.11.201709181750201709181750201709181750.020 as version and it worked fine.

The second question:
By default, Flyway will fail to apply migrations if it find out-of-order migration with the message: 
Validate failed: Detected resolved migration not applied to database

But this behavior can be changed by overriding `"outOfOrder"` configuration flag. See details for command-line runner:

> https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate

Comment: Yes. "outOfOrder" property can ignore if any version is missing. However, when missing migration would be applied to Db, status for that respective migration consider as OutOfOrder.